# Wordpress Audio List - Remove Commas from Title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using wordpress in build audio list, for a post in a site.

Theres no html only this from wordpress

```
[playlist ids="1095,1111,1128,1130,1131,1136,1138,1155,1156,1157,1160,1161,1171"]
```

This is a simple request.
Wordpress puts some commas in all song titles and is annoying. Look at the pic.
[image]

Is there any way to remove them like using jquery, or adding some function to functions.php file.

I have tried using this code I found

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('span.wp-playlist-item-title').blur(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/"/g,''));
});

 </script>
```

No luck

Website: http://www.empoder.co/meditaciones-con-angeles/

Comment: `.blur()` is `onblur`. We cannot see your HTML.

Comment: Hy @PHPglue theres no html, i'm using wordpress list
[playlist ids="1095,1111,1128,1130,1131,1136,1138,1155,1156,1157,1160,1161,1171"]

Comment: Wordpress generates your HTML, in this case.

Comment: Posted the URL, thanks for your time ;)

Comment: You should direct your question towards whoever wrote the plugin that adds the `playlist` shortcode.

Comment: How do I contact directly to wordpress :D, I think you didn't read my post, its a wordpress function, theres no pluging involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "translate"/edit the following *gettext* string:

`&#8220;%s&#8221;`

in the following *context* only:

*playlist item title*

Which you can, for example, do so via the [WPML plugin](https://wpml.org/) (paid) or [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) (it's free, but I haven't tested it).

Alternatively, add this PHP snippet using [My Custom Functions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/) or if you're comfortable, add it to the theme's *functions.php* file:

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', function ( $translation, $text, $context, $domain ) {
    if ( 'default'        === $domain  &&
    'playlist item title' === $context &&
    '&#8220;%s&#8221;'    === $text ) {
        return '%s';
    }

    return $translation;
}, 10, 4 );
```

*And be sure to remove the JS code you added on that page.*

Comment: 100% confirm, did it with LOCO TRANSLATE!! worked, and tried your function, both worked fine. Thanks man!!

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

This filter added to my functions file is not removing the " from the title.

`add_filter('gettext_with_context', function($translated, $text, $context, $domain){ if($context = 'playlist item title' && $text == '&#8220;%s&#8221;') $translated = "%s"; return $translated; }, 10, 4);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30020462)